# How can i hide a TinyMCE contol bar if the field is inactive?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Requirements:

- on field enter show TinyMCE controll bar
- on leave hide the TinyMCE controll bar

I would do this with blur/focus right? What do i need to do, to show and hide the controll bar of tinymce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup parameter should be set to your tinymce init configuration in order to work (jQuery js library needed).

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, event) {
        $(ed.getBody()).blur(function() {
          $('#' + ed.id + '_tbl '+'.mceToolbar').hide();
        });

        $(ed.getBody()).focus(function() {
          $('#' + ed.id + '_tbl '+'.mceToolbar').show();
        });

    });
},
```

Comment: After searching a bit i dont think there is a function by tinymce who directly provides a toolbar toggle. If that is incorrect please tell me, i now used show() / hide() in focus / blur functions. Thanks Thariama

Comment: the only thing i know of is to define the toolbar external - then it behaves more or less that way: theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "external", (you may give it a try)

Answer (score 0):

If it just hide unhide the Toolbar there is a a plugin I think with the latest Tinymce we have some option . Will this work ?
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.ui.Toolbar.remove